# How do I turn points from function in to a list to plot a complete graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, graph-theory

So I have made a function plot_line(p1,p2) that takes two points as input arguments and plots the line between them. The two input arguments are
lists or tuples specifying x- and y-coordinates, i.e., p1 =(x1,y1). Now further i want to make a function for example: complete_graph(points) that takes a list of
points and plots the complete graph on those points. I have tried to modify the plot_line function from so that it only calls plot() but not show(). I wish for the complete graph to  be drawn by looping over the points and calling plot_line for each pair, and finally calling show()after the loop, how would I do that?

I have this code for now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

"Task a)"
#call function tuple
def cor_tup(x, y): #coordinates for tuple
    return(x,y)

def plotline(p1,p2):
    x=(p1[0],p2[0]) #x values
    y=(p1[1],p2[1])#y values
    plt.plot(x, y, "-o", label="x,y") #plot the points in graph
    
x1=int(input('enter first desired x value:'))
y1=int(input('enter first desired y value:'))
x2=int(input('enter second desired x value:'))
y2=int(input('enter second desired y value:'))

p1=cor_tup(x1,y1)
p2=cor_tup(x2,y2)

plotline(p1,p2)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend
plt.axis([-5,5,-5,5])
plt.title('Linear function')
plt.show()
```

The plot is supposed to look like this in the end result, but I don't get it like that:

[image: desired plot]

Answer (score 1):

This will make you a nice little house whit a star inside (and should work for any list of tuples)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotline(p1, p2):
    x=(p1[0],p2[0]) #x values
    y=(p1[1],p2[1])#y values
    plt.plot(x, y, "-b", label="x,y") #plot the points in graph

data = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (0.5, 1.5)]

for i, xy in enumerate(data):
    for xy2 in data[i+1:]:
        plotline(xy, xy2)

x = [d[0] for d in data]
y = [d[1] for d in data]
plt.plot(x, y, 'o',color='r')
plt.show()
```

If you need to get the input from the user you can keep your input code.

Note that I am iterating only from `data[i+1:]` in the inner loop and incrementing i in the outer loop through `enumerate` to avoid duplicate lines (every point should be connected only once with the others)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I quite like how little amount of code this is but I don't quite get the for loop with the enumerate, how does it join the verticies without redrawing the existing lines between them?

Comment: You start from the first point (i=0) and you draw all the connecting lines to the other points with the inner loop, but starting from i+1 because you do not want to connect the point with itself. Then you move to the second point (i=1) but you already drew the line connecting the point i=0 and i=1 in the previous iteration (when i=0). So you need to skip both the previous point and the current point. By using `data[i+1]` in the inner loop you ensure that you skip connecting the point with itself and with the previous ones you already connected. Does this clarify?

Comment: Ah yes, makes alot more sense now. I am still confused about the syntax of ```for i, xy in enumerate(data)``` about what that actually does, but i don't often use enumerate or ```for i, n``` two variables like that in a for loop.

Comment: `enumerate` it is a very useful builtin. Technically it returns an iterator of tuples composed by the index of each element of the iteratable you are enumerating and each element itself. In simple terms it is a better way of writing the following: `for i in range(len(mylist)): do_smth_with(mylist[i])`

Answer (score 0):

I think i made something that works as what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

"Task a)"
#call function tuple
def cor_tup(x, y): #coordinates for tuple
    return(x,y)

def plotline(p1, p2):
    x=(p1[0],p2[0]) #x values
    y=(p1[1],p2[1])#y values
    plt.plot(x, y, "-o", label="x,y") #plot the points in graph


def Line_of_points(totalLines):

    listOfPoints = []
    
    for i in range(1, totalLines+1):
        currentx = int(input("Enter first x point " + str(i) + " : "))
        currenty = int(input("Enter first y point " + str(i) + " : "))
        currentPoint1 = (currentx, currenty)

        currentx = int(input("Enter second x point " + str(i) + " : "))
        currenty = int(input("Enter second y point " + str(i) + " : "))
        currentPoint2 = (currentx, currenty)

        points = (currentPoint1, currentPoint2)
        
        listOfPoints.append(points)   
    
    return listOfPoints


def Draw_All_Points(pointList):
    counter = 0

    while counter < len(pointList):
        if counter <= len(pointList)-1: #so at last point, doesnt access out of list len
            firstPoint = pointList[counter][0]
            secondPoint = pointList[counter][1]
            print(firstPoint, secondPoint)
            

            plotline(firstPoint, secondPoint)
            
        else:
            break

        counter += 1

    
lineOfPoints = Line_of_points(2)
Draw_All_Points(lineOfPoints)



plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend
plt.axis([-5,5,-5,5])
plt.title('Linear function')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want a rectangle drawn, just pass in 4 into the Line_of_points function, and input something like:  0,0    0,1    2,1    2,0    0,0

Comment: need for ((0, 0),(1, 0),(0, 1),(1, 1)) and
then the points (1, 0),(α, α),(0, 1),(−α, α),(−1, 0),(−α, −α),(0, −1),(α, −α) where α=sqrt2/2

Comment: Do you want the points drawn consecutive of one another or, you give it a start point and then it draws it to an end point?

Comment: I want the point to give a start point and then draw to a end point, and then restart u know so there are a bunch of lines that connect to each other and form a figure. Like the one on the right https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8ZZ.png

Comment: Is this what you mean (edited answer), for a rectangle, you want a point at (0,0) (0,1) then (0,1) (1,1)  then (1,1) (1,0), and (1,0)(0,0) and for the diagonal something like (0,0)(1,1)?

Comment: uhm now i get https://imgur.com/a/jPSK01p for Enter x1:0

Enter y1:0

Enter second x1:1

Enter second y1:0

Enter x2:0

Enter y2:1

Enter second x2:1

Enter second y2:1

Comment: Ok i might not be understanding completely what it is you want. From that function ```Enter x1:0 Enter y1:0 Enter second x1:1 Enter second y1:0 Enter x2:0 Enter y2:1 Enter second x2:1 Enter second y2:1 ``` youre drawing a line from the point (0,0) to (1,0) which is that flat blue line at the bottom? if you want to connect the sides and diagonals do (for the left side) Enter x1: 0, Enter y1: 0   Enter x1 second: 0    Enter y1 second: 1